# IReliableDictionary 2 vs IReliableDictionary

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Can anyone explain why service fabric has both `IReliableDictionary` and `IReliableDictionary2` where `IReliableDictionary` DERIVES from `IReliableDictionary2`?  It makes no sense and the documentation doesn't appear to explain it.  Which one are you supposed to use?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.collections.ireliabledictionary-2?view=azure-dotnet

Proof: 
[image]

Comment: Typo causing the auto doc generation thingy to create a new section perhaps? Is `IReliableDictionary2` a real interface in the library?

Comment: yep, and I added a screenshot with proof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IReliableDictionary2` has an additional property `Count` which is persisted alongside the collection's entries. This allows quick access to the number of entries in the collection, as usually you'd have to enumerate over its entries and calculate the count.

This is not very clear from the API documentation, merely seeing "Oh this has an extra count property" does not, to me, alert that "You should use this if you need to readily access the count". Perhaps you could open an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-sdk-dotnet/blob/d778ccab21f1cd47f267b40340d5feae075a59e0/xml/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Data.Collections/IReliableDictionary2%602.xml) explaining how it's not clear, or edit it and create a PR!

Answer (score 6):

You are reading the documentation incorrectly. "Derived", means that IReliableDictionary2 is derived from IReliableDictionary. For proof look at ICollection interface in .Net, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=netframework-4.7.

You want use IReliableDictionary2 if you need to use Count that doesn't enumerate all items in the dictionary or key enumeration.

Comment: ah.. you're right i was reading the documentation incorrectly.